# ASP.NET IConfiguration, how to iterate or enumerate Providers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configurationmanager

I am trying to write a test to verify that X providers are loaded in a certain scenario.

I can resolve the `IConfiguration` object, how can I tell how many `IConfigurationProviders` are in it?

In my startup, I use totally bog standard Configuration in my Program

```
IConfiguration configuration = null;
var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        configuration = hostContext.Configuration;
        var startup = new Startup(hostContext.Configuration, hostContext.HostingEnvironment);
        //startup.ConfigureServices(services);
    })

    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
    {
        config.AddAzureKeyVaultsFromConfig();
    });

builder.Build();
return configuration;
```

When I'm debugging, I can see my list of Providers when I hover over `configuration`.

[image]

What I would want to do is see that there are 4 providers.  I would also want to check and see what type the providers are.

If I use `Enumerate()` it just gives me a flattened list of all of the values and discards which provider it came from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object you have here is actually an [`IConfigurationRoot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfigurationroot?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0), and that happens to also implement `IConfiguration`. So if you treat it as such, you can access the [`Providers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfigurationroot.providers?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfigurationRoot_Providers) property. For example:

```
IConfigurationRoot configuration = null;

// snip the rest of your code

var providerCount = configuration.Providers.Count();
```

Comment: This worked once I added a reference to `System.Linq` and cast to the `IConfigurationRoot` type `((IConfigurationRoot)configNew).Providers.Count();`

Comment: Sorry, I meant to make the configuration object of type `IConfigurationRoot`. I'd rather do that than cast it if I were you.

Comment: This seems straightforward but I am not grokking the change I should make to do this :).  Could you elaborate what would be preferable rather than casting like this?

Comment: Using the IConfigurationRoot type instead of IConfigurationRoot. Then you don't need to carry later on.